# Firebase prevent malicious update in real-time database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to develop a real-time anonymous queue with firebase real-time database. The concept is when a person visits my webpage, it will generate a UUID and insert a record at firebase DB. Based on the position of the UUID, I will determine that user's position in the queue. Here is the sample of the documents:-

```
{
    _random_key_1: {
        uuid: '47c044c7-da32-4e37-a416-cb2d621e0e39',
        is_finished: false
    },
    _random_key_2: {
        uuid: 'bcb8e01f-7745-43aa-9897-fd217d755769',
        is_finished: false
    },
    _random_key_3: {
        uuid: 'cdf754bd-4626-4da1-b676-9ebe87927a04',
        is_finished: false
    },
}
```

Here, the position of the user with queue id `cdf754bd-4626-4da1-b676-9ebe87927a04` is 3. When someone in front of a queue finishes his thing, I will update his queue object with `is_finished: true` and recalculate the position of everyone else connected to this DB.

For example, let's say the first user (`47c044c7-da32-4e37-a416-cb2d621e0e39`) finishes his thing. Here is how the documents will look

```
{
    _random_key_1: {
        uuid: '47c044c7-da32-4e37-a416-cb2d621e0e39',
        is_finished: true
    },
    _random_key_2: {
        uuid: 'bcb8e01f-7745-43aa-9897-fd217d755769',
        is_finished: false
    },
    _random_key_3: {
        uuid: 'cdf754bd-4626-4da1-b676-9ebe87927a04',
        is_finished: false
    },
}
```

Now, the position of the user with queue id `cdf754bd-4626-4da1-b676-9ebe87927a04` is two because there is only one person with an unfinished task in front of him.

The problem is since I'm all of this from frontend (because I'm expecting heavy load at the application and not planning to overload my backend server), anyone can steal my firebase credentials and maliciously set `is_finished = true` to everyone in front of him.

How do I prevent such a scenario?

Comment: What does mean (in IT business logic terms) "When someone in front of a queue finishes his thing"? Where the code which decides/calculates if a "thing is finished" is executed?

Comment: It can be anything such as purchasing a product. The person who is at the front of the queue, will be allowed to make purchases. And once the purchase is complete, the front end will fire an update request to update his record as is_confirmed = true.

Comment: As you wrote in your question, doing that from the front-end is not a correct approach. In the Firebase ecosystem, [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) are the way to execute code in the back-end.

Comment: I don't understand! Let's say I moved all my logic to the cloud function, but I still need to read the realtime database from the frontend. That means exposing my API key in the frontend. What's stopping hackers from using the key, retrieve all the documents and modify as they see fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either Firebase's server-side security rules to control what users can write. Since these are enforced on the server, users can't bypass them from the client-side code.

For example, if a user should only be able to add an item with `is_finished` set to false, you can [use a validation rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#validaterules) to enforce that. This does require that you can distinguish regular users from the user that processes the queue items, so typically means you'll either want to use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) to identify them - or run the processing code with one of Firebase's Admin SDK in a trusted environment (such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions/Cloud Run that Renaud mentioned).

Also consider using [Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check), which makes it much harder for a malicious user to run their own code with your configuration keys. While this will help against abuse, it is not a guarantee that all malicious use is eliminated, so you should still take the approach described above too.

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I have decided to move all of my write operations to cloud functions and set the validation rules to read-only so that even if someone else got my API key, they would only be able to read the data. Do you think there is any problem with this approach?

Comment: I can't say whether there's any problem, but it's a valid approach - as is securing through authentication and security rules. 